# Echoing data from one table that matches conditions from another

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display some data from a MYSQL database in a table format on my webpage. **So everyone dosent get confused between the website table and mysql table, i'll call the website table 'web table' from now on.**

Most of the data for this web table is being pulled from a MYSQL table called 'image', however for one of the web table's columns I want to display data from a different MYSQL table (within the same database) called 'users'.

Both 'image' and 'users' have a 'user_id' field, so I was looking to find the entry in 'users' where 'user_id' matched the 'user_id' in image.

Here is the code I have so far. I know it is depreciated, but his project requires it.

For your reference, the user_id field from 'image' is echo'd as `$data[1]`

```
mysql_connect('XX','XX','XX');
mysql_select_db('XX')

$order = "SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY id";

$result = mysql_query($order) or die ("Bad query: " . mysql_error() );  

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>'SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE users.user_id = $data[1]'</td><td>$data[2]</td><td>$data[3]</td></tr>");
}
```

Cheers in advanced. I know this is probably basic, but I'm not great with PHP.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html might be interesting.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's 2 questions in here? First you want make a query where one table conditions matches another, and another question how to `echo` result by creating html table? You'd better edit your question cause this will probably be closed.. @Cobra_Fast would be difficult for him :) there's better source like http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html tutorial..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have all data you need with a single `INNER JOIN` query

```
$order = "SELECT a.*, b.full_name FROM image a INNER JOIN user b ON a.user_id = b.user_id ORDER BY a.id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('XX','XX','XX');
mysql_select_db('XX')

$order = "SELECT * FROM image as i, users as u WHERE  i.user_id =u.user_id ORDER BY i.id";

$result = mysql_query($order) or die ("Bad query: " . mysql_error() );  

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

  <tr><td><?php echo $data[1]?></td><td><?php echo $data[2]?></td><td><?php echo $data[3]?></td><td><?php echo $data[4]?></td></tr>;

<?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here.

```
    <?php 
 while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    ?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td><td><?php $sql_res = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE users.user_id ="'.$data[1].'"')); ?></td><td><?php echo $data[2] ?></td><td><?php echo $sql_res['full_name'] ?></td></tr>

  <?php
}

?>
```